# How do I change the date filter format in the Data View Web Part toolbar?

Tags: data-view-web-part, filter

I have added a toolbar to the **DVWP** and enabled the Filter option. When I click on the filter, the **Due Date** field displays choices as `Saturday, September 11, 2010`. Within the DVWP I have the format set to `mm/dd/yyyy`. The differing formats seem to prevent the filter from working.

How I can change the format in the filter drop-down?

Comment: It's hard to know how to answer this without seeing the XSL as you've adapted it. Or are you simply making choices in the Common Dialogs?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this question? If yes, could you post it as an answer?